# update ..set..select: how to apply it on the entire column

Tags: postgresql

How can I obtain the result expected from the following query, currently not supported in postgres [enter link description here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html), (see last section on compatibility)

> UPDATE accounts SET (contact_last_name, contact_first_name) =
>       (SELECT last_name, first_name FROM salesmen
>        WHERE salesmen.id = accounts.sales_id);

Actually I am adding a new empty column to a table and fill it with the content of a column of equal size and type from another table/view

```
do $$DECLARE
    k record;
    _current_view text := '';
    _current_var text := '';
    _new_column_sql text := '';
    _insert_sql text := '';
    _select_sql text := '';

    begin
        for k in SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='train'
        and column_name <> 'action' 
        loop
            _current_view := 'av_' || k.column_name;
            _current_var := k.column_name;

            _new_column_sql := 'alter table train_average_imputed add column ' || _current_var || ' float';

            _select_sql := 'select prob as ' || _current_var || ' from ' || _current_view || ', train 
                where train.' || _current_var || '=' || _current_view || '.' || _current_var ;

            _insert_sql := 'insert into train_average_imputed(' || _current_var || ') ' || _select_sql;

            raise notice '%', _select_sql;
            --EXECUTE _test_sql;
            EXECUTE _new_column_sql;
            EXECUTE _insert_sql;
            exit;
        end loop;
        end$$;
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Actually I need to update along the rows number, I tried using this

```
drop table play2;
create table play2 as (select action from play);
alter table play2 add column color text;

with trans_table as(select color, row_number() over() as rn from play2)
update trans_table set color = a.color from (
    select color, row_number() over() as rn from play) as a
where trans_table.rn =a.rn;
```

but I got the following error

```
DROP TABLE
SELECT 100
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  relation "trans_table" does not exist
LINE 2: update trans_table set color = a.color from (
           ^
```

I don't see how my code is  at odd with the the postgres `with` page [enter link description here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html). Note that if I use a `select` instead of a `update` query after the `with` it returns the expected result.

**UPDATE 2**

As Igor suggested, just needed to copy the table and add columns from there.

Comment: Use `UPDATE ... FROM`. Details in the manual page you linked to.

Comment: Why cant you create a full table from one `SELECT`? Like `CREATE TABLE play2 AS SELECT action, color FROM play`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET (contact_last_name, contact_first_name) = (SELECT last_name, first_name FROM salesmen WHERE salesmen.id = accounts.sales_id);
```

Can be written in Postgres as:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET contact_last_name = salesmen.last_name,
    contact_first_name = salesmen.first_name 
FROM salesmen 
WHERE salesmen.id = accounts.sales_id;
```

Comment: thanks Igor. Actually I realise I need to access the rows number to map values from one table to the other. I have updated the thread accordingly.